# Chart.js and Django for more than one user

Tags: django, chart.js

I am in the process of creating a web application but when i generate a chart with chart.js, I save the save the chart's data on (site url)/data. This means that anyone who enters the site will see that chart.

Is there a way I can store data that is dependent on the user. Meaning that everyone can see different graphs.

Comment: How do you save data?

Comment: I save the data with the rest_framework to my site/data. (for example: google.com/data)